# Try to find Angular DevTools Extension for Edge

Tags: angular, microsoft-edge

I want to install the Angular DevTools extension into Edge. It is not on the  Edge Web Store and Chrome Web Store won't allow me to install it into Edge. Is there another location where I can install the extension?

Comment: Please include the steps you’ve taken and what you mean by “won’t allow me”. Suggest following link: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/add-turn-off-or-remove-extensions-in-microsoft-edge-9c0ec68c-2fbc-2f2c-9ff0-bdc76f46b026

Comment: How about the issue? Is my answer below helpful to deal with the issue? I am glad to help if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 2):

Have you allowed extensions from other stores in Edge? You can follow the steps below to install Angular DevTools extension in Edge:

1. Navigate to `edge://extensions/` in Edge.
2. Turn on **Allow extensions from other stores**.
3. Navigate to Angular DevTools extension page in Edge and click **Add to Chrome** to install the extension in Edge.

[image]

[image]

If you still can't add the extension successfully in Edge, you can provide if there's any error message when install and provide screenshots about the issue.